# Should I use std::endl after every cout statement?

Tags: c++

So I am a complete beginner in C++. I am following the book C++ primer. The author always uses std::endl after every std::cout statement to flush the buffer. My quesion is should I always use std::endl?

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int sum=0,val=1;
    while(val<=10)
    {
        sum+=val;
        ++val;
    }
    std::cout<<"Sum of the 1 to 10 is: "<<sum<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whether it should or should not be used depends entirely on rare, specific, application-specific details. 99.9% of the time it does not matter.

Comment: The cases where you should use `std::endl` are quite rare.

Comment: You should use `std::endl` when you are done printing on the current line and want to move to the next line. It is perfectly ok to use several `std::cout << "something"` without `std::endl` if you want to put several different things on the same line. Note that depending on your terminal app, they may not display until you print the final `std::endl`.

Comment: @LevM. To end a line you can use `\n`. `std::endl` is to end a line **and** to flush the stream. Flushing the stream on every new line is not always desired

Comment: *My question is should I always use `std::endl`?*  I never use `std::endl`, instead I used `"\n"`.  If I really need to flush the buffer, I'll use `std::flush`.